# string/integer associations in C

Tags: c, string, hash, integer, associations

I'd like a suggestion in c language for the following problem:

I need an association between strings and integers like this:

```
"foo" => 45,
"bar" => 1023,
 etc...
```

and be able to find the string using the associated integer and the integer using the associated string.
For string to integer I can use hash tables but I'll loose the way back.

The simple solution that I'm using but which is very slow is to create a table:
    static param_t params [] = {
        { "foo", 45 },
        { "bar", 1023 },
    ...
    };
and using two functions compare each entry (string or integer) to get the string or the integer.
This works perfectly by this is linear search which is very slow.
What could I use to have a search algorithm in O(1) to find a string and O(size of string) to find the integer?
Any ideas?

Comment: How about Hashmaps ? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1222055

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to implement lookup tables, preferably sorted by the integer value ("primary key").

```
typedef enum
{
  FOO_INDEX,
  BAR_INDEX,
  ...  
  N
} some_t;

const int int_array [] =  // values sorted in ascending order, smallest first
{
  45,
  1023,
  ...
};

const char* str_array [] =
{
  "foo",
  "bar",
  ...
};
```

Now you can use `int_array[FOO_INDEX]` and `str_array[FOO_INDEX]` to get the desired data.

Since these are constant tables set at compile-time, you can sort the data. All lookups can then be done with binary search, O(log n). If you have the integer value but need to know the index, perform a binary search on the int_array. And once you have found the index, you get instant lookup from there.

For this to work, both arrays must have the exact size `N`. To ensure array sizes and data integrity inside those arrays, use a compile-time assert:

```
static_assert(sizeof(int_array)/sizeof(*int_array) == N, "Bad int_array");
static_assert(sizeof(str_array)/sizeof(*str_array) == N, "Bad str_array");
```

Comment: Good answer, but worth noting that if you use static_assertion, arrays must be declared without `N` (like `const int int_array [] = { ... }`). Otherwise assertion won't detect too short initializer list.

Comment: @user694733 Oh of course, I'm not sure what I was thinking. I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Isn't `static_assert` C++?

Comment: ok but how I get the string "bar" having the integer 1023? I still need a way to find it's position.

Comment: @user3710871 "If you have the integer value but need to know the index, perform a binary search on the int_array." So when searching for 1024, you'll get the index 1 (equal to BAR_INDEX). Then simply access `str_array[1]` to get the corresponding string.

Comment: ok and how do you do the opposite? bar => 1023? I thing gperf should be used for this problem, the lookup table seems limited if you don't have to index.

Answer (score 0):

Sort your list with [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) first, and then use [`bsearch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch) to find items. It's not O(1), but at least it is O(log(n)).

Answer (score 0):

Use two hashmaps. One for the association from integer to string and another one for the association from string to integer.

Comment: Hash maps are only really needed when you have the string and need to get the integer, i.e. when the string is the primary key. Even then, you could probably just use a plain sorted table. Though hash maps are useful if duplicates are allowed.

Comment: If I already had a Hashmap implementation (like I would if this had been perl or Java) I would use it both ways. Only if I had to implement one myself I would consider using something else for the association from integer to string.

Answer (score 0):

An inefficient way would be to kind of convert it to base 256. First-letter-ASCII times 256 in the power of 0 (1) PLUS Second-letter-ASCII times 256 in the power of 1 and so on. Very inefficient (Because long won't be enough so either contain the number in another string or use a mathematical C library. I know there are hashes in Ruby and Perl and it's basically an array that you get into with a certain key (can be a string) but I don't know how it's working.